# Calculating a file size in TASM assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm

I was given an assignment that sounds somewhat like this

> Write a program in Intel x86 assembly which takes parameters from the console (user input): the first parameter - file size in bytes, the others - full paths to the directories that have to be analyzed. The program finds files in the given directories that are larger then the specified size, then it changes their access attribute to read-only.  Also, the program outputs a numbered list of such files into a separate file

( Sorry for poor translation, English is my second language ).

So I have written some code to display a helping message if needed; create the results file; store the given size in a buffer; go through directories and analyze files;

```
.model small ; kiek skirti atminties programai

.stack 100h ; steko dydis

.data ; data segmento pradžia

    message                 db      "Nr.", 10 dup (' '), "Pavadinimas", 10 dup (' '), "Dydis (B)", 3 dup (' '), '$' ; pirma žinutė rezultatų faile
    resultFile_n            db      "rez.txt", 0 ; rezultatų failo pavadinimas                                                          
    help                    db      "Pirmasis parametras - failo dydis baitais,", 10, 13, "visi kiti - pilni keliai iki norimu nagrineti direktoriju.$" ; pagalbos pranešimas
    file                    dw      ?   ; failo handleris
    ; DTA start
    DTA                     db      255 dup( 0 )    ; data transfer address
    fileName                db      250 dup ( 0 )   ; failo pavadinimas
    fileName_n              dw      0
    fileSize                db      10 dup ( '0' )  ; failo dydis
    fileSize_n              dw      0
    ; DTA end
    sizeHigh                dw      0
    sizeLow                 dw      0
    remainderHigh           dw      0
    remainderLow            dw      0
    newLine                 db      0Dh, 0Ah
    space                   db      ' '
    ; parametrų bufferis start
    buffer_asize            db      0h  ; bufferio dydis
    buffer                  db      255 dup ( ? ); buferis, kuriam saugosiu parametrų eilutę
    ; parametrų bufferis end
    ; vartotojo įvesto dydžio bufferis start
    sizeBuffer_asize        db      0h  ; actual size
    sizeBuffer              db      255 dup ( ? )
    ; vartotojo įvesto dydžio bufferis end
    ; directory buffer start
    directory_asize         dw      0h
    directoryBuffer         db      254 dup ( ? ), 0
    ; directory buffer end


.code

start:

    mov ax, @data               ; perkeliam iš data į registrą ax
    mov ds, ax                  ; perkeliam iš ax į data segmentą

    xor ch, ch                  ; nunulinam ch, nes naudosim cl
    mov cl, es:[80h]            ; programos paleidimo parametrų simbolių skaičius, kuris rašomas ES 80h baite
    cmp cx, 0                   ; jei vartotojas nedavė jokių parametrų
    je Exit1                    ; nereikia nieko tikrinti, programą užbaigam
    mov bx, 81h                 ; programos paleidimo parametrai rašomi ES nuo 81h baito, įmetam į bazinį registrą, kad galėtumėm adresuoti

    FindHelp:                   ; ieškom pagalbos simbolio

        cmp es:[bx], '?/'       ; lyginam pagalbos pranešimo simbolį su simboliu esančiu BX poslinkiu ES
        ; atmintyje jaunesnysis baitas saugomas pirmiau,
        ; todėl pirmasis baitas įrašomas į bl, antras į bh
        ; dėl to /? virsta į ?/

        je SendHelp             ; reikia spausdinti pagalbos pranešimą
        inc bx                  ; didinam bx ( poslinkį )
        loop FindHelp           ; jei dar nepatikrinom visų parametrų - tikrinam toliau

        jmp AllParamsChecked    ; jei visi parametrai patikrinti, tai nereikia spausdinti pagalbos pranešimo

    SendHelp:                   ; spausdinam pagalbos pranešimą

        mov ah, 9
        lea dx, help
        int 21h
        jmp Exit1

    AllParamsChecked:                   ; tęsiam programą, jei nereikia spausdinti pagalbos pranešimo

        xor cx, cx              ; nustatom failo atributą į 0 ( read-only )
        mov ah, 3Ch             ; failo sukūrimo komanda
        lea dx, resultFile_n    ; failo vardas
        int 21h                 ; kuriam rezultatų failą
        mov file, ax            ; išsisaugom handlerį velėsniam darbui su failu

        mov ah, 40h             ; spausdinam pirmą eilutę rezultatų faile
        mov bx, file
        mov cx, 46d             ; kiek baitų įrašyti
        lea dx, message
        int 21h

        mov bx, file            ; pereinam į naują eilutę
        mov cx, 2d
        mov ah, 40h
        lea dx, newLine
        int 21h

        mov ah, 1Ah             ; nurodau DTA 
        lea dx, DTA
        int 21h

        mov cl, es:[80h]        ; programos paleidimo parametrų simbolių skaičius paimamas iš ES 80h baito
        dec cl                  
        mov buffer_asize, cl    ; išsaugom buferio dydį kintamąjame
        cmp cl, 0h
        jz Exit1                ; jei nėra parametrų, baigiam programą

        mov si, 0               ; poslinkį nustatom į 0
        xor ch, ch              ; nunulinam ch, nes ciklo skaitliukui naudosim CX ( mums reikia tik CL reikšmės )

        ReadLoop:   ; skaitom visus vartotojo įvestus parametrus ( failo dydį ir direktorijas )

            mov al, es:[82h + si]   ; skaitom parametrus iš ES segmento poslinkiu SI, į AL
            mov [ buffer + si ], al ; iš AL perkeliam į bufferį tolesniam darbui
            inc si                  ; didinam poslinkį

        loop ReadLoop


        ; Exit'as nes vienu jumpu nenušoksim
        jmp Next1

        Exit1:
            jmp Finish

        Next1:
        ; End Exit'as

        xor bx, bx
        xor dx, dx
        mov dl, buffer_asize

        SaveSize:   ; išsaugom vartotojo įvestą dydį bufferyje lyginimui

            cmp bx, dx
            jae Exit2                   ; jei nėra direktorijų baigiam programą
            cmp [ buffer + bx ], ' '    ; dydis parametrų eilutėje įrašytas iki pirmo tarpo
            je NextDirectory

            mov cl, [ buffer + bx ]
            mov [ sizeBuffer + bx ], cl
            inc bx                  ; pereinam į kitą simbolį
            inc sizeBuffer_asize    ; didinam dydžio ilgį
            jmp SaveSize

        NextDirectory:

            xor dx, dx
            mov dl, buffer_asize
            cmp bx, dx
            jae Exit2

            xor si, si  ; jei imam kitą direktoriją, tai pradedam bufferį pildyt iš naujo
            inc bx  ; praleidžiam tarpą

            Directory:  ; aprodojam direktoriją

                xor dx, dx
                mov dl, buffer_asize
                cmp dx, bx
                je EndReading

                cmp [ buffer + bx ], ' '    ; jei ne tarpas, reiškias vis dar skaitom simbolius tos pačios direktorijos
                je EndReading

                mov al, [ buffer + bx ]
                mov [ directoryBuffer + si ], al

                inc si
                inc bx

                jmp Directory

            EndReading:

                ; prie direktorijos galo pridedu *.*, kad ieškotų visų failų toje direktorijoje
                mov [ directoryBuffer + si ], '*'
                inc si
                mov [ directoryBuffer + si ], '.'
                inc si
                mov [ directoryBuffer + si ], '*'
                inc si
                mov [ directoryBuffer + si ], 0

                mov directory_asize, si

                ; atranda pirmą failą nurodytoje direktorijoje
                mov ah, 4Eh ; find first ASCIZ
                xor cx, cx 
                lea dx, directoryBuffer
                int 21h
                jc Exit2    ; jei klaida

                jmp ProcessFile

            ; Exit'as2
            jmp Next2
            Exit2:
                jmp Finish
            Next2:
            ;End exit'as 2

            NextFile: ; ieško kitų failų nurodytoje direktorijoje

                mov ah, 4Fh
                xor cx, cx
                lea dx, directoryBuffer
                int 21h
                jc NextDirectory    ; jei nėra failų

        ProcessFile:
            ; failo dydis saugomas dviejuose žodžiuose = keturiuose baituose = 32 bit
            ; 32 bit skaičių reikia konvertuoti į ASCII simbolį
            mov dh, [ DTA + 1Dh ]
            mov dl, [ DTA + 1Ch ]
            mov sizeHigh, dx

            mov ah, [ DTA + 1Bh ]
            mov al, [ DTA + 1Ah ]
            mov sizeLow, ax

            xor si, si

            GetFileSize: ;//


            jmp Next3

            NextFile1:
                jmp NextFile

            Next3:


            CompareSize: ;//


            WriteToFile:    

                mov fileSize_n, si
                xor si, si
                xor ax, ax
                mov di, 1Eh

                GetFileName: 

                    cmp [ DTA + di ], 0
                    je Write

                    mov al, [ DTA + di ]
                    mov [ fileName + si ], al

                    inc di
                    inc si

                    jmp GetFileName

            Write:

                mov fileName_n, si

                push bx

                mov ah, 43h ; padarom read only
                mov al, 01h
                mov cx, 01h
                lea dx, fileName
                int 21h 

                ; call SpaceLoop

                mov ah, 40h 
                mov bx, file
                mov cx, fileName_n
                lea dx, fileName
                int 21h

                ; call SpaceLoop

                ; mov ah, 40h
                ; mov bx, file
                ; mov cx, 4d
                ; lea dx, sizeLow
                ; int 21h

                mov bx, file            ; pereinam į naują eilutę
                mov cx, 2d
                mov ah, 40h
                lea dx, newLine
                int 21h

                pop bx

                jmp NextFile1

    Finish:         ; užbaigiam programą

        mov ah, 3Eh     ; uždarom failą
        mov bx, file
        int 21h

        mov ah, 4Ch     ; returning to dos, interrupto komandos numeris.
        mov al, 0       ; no errors
        int 21h         ; dos interrupt

    SpaceLoop proc

        mov cx, 13

        loop1:

            push cx

            mov bx, file
            mov cx, 1d
            mov ah, 40h
            lea dx, space
            int 21h

            pop cx

        loop loop1
        ret

    SpaceLoop endp

end start
```

( The comments are in my native language, so ignore them )

This is where the problem comes: I don't know how to calculate and store the size of a file and it's name in separate buffers.

How should that be done?

Other comments and recommendations are also welcome.

Comment: The size is in the DTA as you seem to know. Not sure why your `GetSize` is using a loop. Also no idea why you need to store the size or the name. Just process the file if the condition holds.

Comment: I need to save the size in order to compare it to the user specified size. Then if its larger, i have to store it in the results file. The size is saved in 1A-1D bytes of the DTA. So loop should go through this range and transfer it to a different buffer, but for some reason it doesn't work :(

Comment: There is no need to copy it, but if you want to, it's easier without a loop. That said, the loop kinda looks okay at first glance, how does it not work?

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, I can compare them directly. Also, if I add a simple output to a file from this newly filled file size buffer, right after GetSize label, it outputs nothing, not even a space or a newline. Maybe there's a mistake somewhere else - maybe it doesn't even get to the loop, maybe the code above is flawed. I will debug it later and provide the results. Btw, how to copy it to the buffer without a loop ?

Comment: For example, `mov ax, [dta+1ah]; mov dx, [dta+1ch]; mov [buf], ax; mov [buf+2], dx`

Comment: a guess (check in debugger first): the size is a binary 32 bit number, i.e. for file of size 513 bytes the DTA+1Ah will contain bytes `01 02 00 00`. It's not printable. And to compare it with user inputted size which is string, you should convert the string into 32b integer, which may be a bit tricky in 16b code, not as trivial as 16b ones (but must be answered on SO several times). When you have both values as 32b integers, you can cmp 32b: `mov ax,[userSz+2]` `cmp [dta+1ch],ax` `ja UserSzAOrE` `jb UserSzB` `mov ax,[userSz]` `cmp [dta+1ah],ax` `jae UserSzAOrE` `UserSzB:` ... process file...

Comment: Are you just asking how to convert an integer to a string?  You can print each hit as you find them, you don't need to save the list in memory until the end.  Just open the result file at the start and keep the handle.  (Although that could mean your result-file is found and changed to read-only...)

Comment: I have found a problem : for some reason 4Eh ( find first file in a directory ) throws an error ( carry flag is set ) and the program terminates there. I think the directory that I'm giving is in a wrong format. 

`mov ah, 4Eh
xor cx, cx 
lea dx, directoryBuffer
int 21h
jc Finish`


Here I'm giving a full path ( C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Folder ) with `*.*` at the end - this signifies that all files will be checked ( search attribute ).

Maybe someone has any idea of what is wrong here ?

Comment: P.S. I get "file not found" error after 4Eh interrupt. Maybe @Jester know how to fix this ?

Comment: Haven't checked, but it may very well only work for current directory only, so try `chdir` to `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Folder` first then use `*.*`.

Comment: I use DOSBox, so after lauching it I mount `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Folder` directory as `C`, so I'm always in that directory. This program should work for any directory, no matter if it's current one or not.

I even tried changing the current directory in assembler itself. I have added `lea dx, directoryBuffer
mov ah, 3Bh
int 21h` just before adding `*.*`. Unfortunately nothing changed, I still get the file not found error from find first ASCIZ interrupt.

Comment: But have you changed your pattern to not include the path?

Comment: Well for now, i'm just testing it manually by inputting  \ , which should mean the full path, that's given to the interrupt, is : `C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Folder\ `. But then again, this interrupt has to be given an absolute path, not a relative one. So it shouldn't matter how I input it, as long as it's an absolute path - which I have been trying to implement from the beginning.

Comment: What I am telling you is that the function you use might not support a path, absolute or otherwise. Just use `*.*`, no path and see if that works.

Comment: It doesn't work that way either. P.S. does everytime next file is found ( 4Fh interrupt ) DTA is filled with that files information or is DTA filled only on first file occurrence ( on 4Eh interrupt ).

Comment: Ok, I have at long last fixed the problem - I wasn't skipping spaces, so the filename I was giving to the interrupt was with a space in front, therefore it was wrong. Now I have another issue, I get the filesize from DTA in 32bit number, I divide it into two words : low and high. Also, I have user inputted size in ASCII ( which I will convert into 16bit number if needed ). The problem is that I don't know how to compare these two numbers 32bit and 16bit or even how to convert 32bit number into 16bit number. Maybe someone could help with that ? ( I have updated the original code of the post )